# method.invoke generates IllegalArgumentException:wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, easymock

I have created EasyMock test cases for one method which has method.invoke().One test case runs fine with this code.The second one which should cover the first "if" condition creates this IlegalArguent Exception:Wrong number of arguments.I don't understand which one is incorrect.whether original code or test case.
Please help.

Original code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/invoke/{service}/{method}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Object invokeService(@PathVariable("service") String className,
        @PathVariable("method") String method,
        @RequestParam("ms") String signature,
        @RequestParam("r") String responseType, @RequestBody String[] body)
        throws Exception {
    if (applicationContext != null
            && applicationContext.containsBean(className)) {
        Object obj = applicationContext.getBean(className);
        String temp[] = signature.split(",");
        Object[] arguments = new Object[temp.length];
        Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[temp.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if(temp[i] != null && !temp[i].isEmpty()) {
            Class cls = Class.forName(temp[i]);
            parameterTypes[i] = cls;
            if (temp[i].startsWith("java.lang.")) {
                arguments[i] = body[i];
            } else {
                try {
                    arguments[i] = mapper.readValue(body[i], cls);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                    arguments[i] = body[i];
                }
            }
            }
        }
        Method m = null;
        if(null !=signature && !signature.isEmpty()) {

            m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, parameterTypes);
        } else {
            m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method);
        }

        Object response = m.invoke(obj);
        return response;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("ApplicationContext not properly set");
    }
}
```

Test1(success):

```
    @Test
public void testInvokeServiceNotJavaLang() throws Exception{
    Object obj = new Object();
    String[] body ={ "body" };

    EasyMock.expect(applicationContext.containsBean("String")).andReturn(true);
    EasyMock.expect(applicationContext.getBean("String")).andReturn(obj);

    EasyMock.replay(applicationContext);

    moduleInvocation.invokeService("String", "toString","", "responseType",body );
    EasyMock.verify(applicationContext);
}
```

Test2(IllegalArgumentException:Wrong number of arguments)

```
    @Test
public void testInvokeService() throws Exception{
    Object obj = new Object();
    String[] body ={ "body" };
    EasyMock.expect(applicationContext.containsBean("Object")).andReturn(true);
    EasyMock.expect(applicationContext.getBean("Object")).andReturn(obj);
    EasyMock.replay(applicationContext);

    moduleInvocation.invokeService("Object", "equals", "java.lang.Object", "responseType",body );
    EasyMock.verify(applicationContext);
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception?

Comment: Object response = m.invoke(obj);
at this line i got this error

Comment: Please post full signature for `public Object invokeService`

Comment: I have uploaded full code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your code, In first case you are calling a method `String#toString()` which does not have any parameters and it gets called successfully. In second case you are calling `Object#equals()` method which expects `one argument` as well so you need to pass that argument value as well while using `m.invoke()`, so your code should be for second case

```
  m.invoke(obj,new Object[]{<object to be compared>});
```

and for fist case this will suffice

```
  m.invoke(obj,null);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You should write it something like this:

```
    Method m = null;
    if(null !=signature && !signature.isEmpty()) {

        m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, parameterTypes);
    } else {
        m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method);
        arguments = null;
    }

    Object response = m.invoke(obj, arguments);
    return response;
```

Comment: when I changed that code as "Object response = m.invoke(obj,new Object[]{String.class})" I got "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.String)". Now that case which ran fine has that "IllegalArgumentException:wrong number of arguments"

Comment: Thank You ..It works for me..I have one more doubt.i.e. I want to check that catch block.For that I have to create one exception at "arguments[i] = mapper.readValue(body[i], cls);".Can you suggest one example input for the same.?

Comment: Create a condition where `body[i]` can not be parsed as an object of class represented by `cls`

Comment: `mapper.readValue()` reads a value from first Param (body[i]) of the Type identified by second parameter (cls), so you need to pass the parameter Type such that it should not match with the type of body[i]

Comment: It does not generate Exceptions for my inputs.    String[] body ={ "!@$@^" };    moduleInvocation.invokeService("List", "setApp","java.util.List", "responseType",body );